# If I remove an item from NSMutableArray, will the index of the items be updated?

Tags: ios, nsmutablearray

Say, I have a NSMutableArray which contains 5 items.

```
NSMutableArray *fruitArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:@[@"Apple", @"Pear", @"Peach", @"Banana", @"Orange"]];
```

Now if I remove the third item - Peach from the array, will the index of Banana and Orange change from 3, 4 to 2, 3 respectively?

Thanks

Comment: What happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  Did you bother to read [the documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSMutableArray_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSMutableArray/removeObjectAtIndex%3a)?

> To fill the gap, all elements beyond *index* are moved by subtracting 1 from their index.

Comment: Thanks. I just had an illusion that the document would not mention this.

Comment: ... what do you think documentation is for?